# Where to ask clothing fabric questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to know the difference between several polyester fabrics: plush, flannel, micro fleece, etc.

Where should I ask?

Comment: The difference in what respect? Chemically? Physically? Practically?

Comment: Practically, phisically and in cost

Answer (score 3):

Since you're looking for information on everyday materials, there does not appear to be a currently-existing Stack Exchange site for your question. (I looked through [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), especially the [Life/Arts](https://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts) category.)

There is, however, an Area 51 proposal called ["Arts and Crafts"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77518/arts-and-crafts?referrer=sJh48A_-1z7ivjBCW2knwQ2) that looks like your best hope. (There are several proposed questions about materials there.)

Comment: It seems its not yet created :)

Comment: @samyb8 That's correct. If you'd like to help it get created, you can commit to it and spread the word!